# Break off (ice-cream, spoon)

Tags: spoken-english

A small part of ice-cream is taken (from a brick of ice-cream) on a plate. So if someone is talking about taking a spoon and breaking off a small part, what will be a natural way to describe that:

> Break off a small part of ice-cream with a spoon. (Telling this to a kid)
>
> Break off a little ice-cream with a spoon. .

Is the use of "break off" natural?
And what can be used with "stick ice-creams"?

This is what I mean:
[image]

(That ice-cream on the spoon)

Comment: Interesting question. I thought I could answer, but I would start with "No" and then I'd fall silent. Hm.

Comment: I think "scoop up" would be OK, but I'm not sure that would work with all kinds of ice cream.

Comment: But won't that be used for sccoping it out of the box or something?

Comment: I honestly can't think of a scenario where you wouldn't scoop ice cream out of something, except for ice cream cakes, where standard cake terminology applies.

Comment: Are we talking about something like a Viennetta ice cream here? A rectangular block on a plate, that you want to break a piece off with a spoon? In that sense, I think break off would be fine (since a Viennetta actually does break apart), but if it's just a block of plain ice cream break doesn't seem appropriate (as unless frozen completely solid the ice cream will tend to scoop rather than break).

Comment: If it's very hard, you would probably need to use a knife (or a chisel!) so maybe 'cut' is the word to use. If it's quite soft, you would scoop it with a spoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker, talking about "breaking off" ice cream certainly sounds  weird. "breaking off", when in the context of food, is usually used when talking about something crisp, like a cookie - you could break off a piece of cookie, for example - as it has the connotation of just using your hands to snap a small part off.

Instead, I'd go with "take off" in this case, or even just "take".

> Take off a little with a spoon.

> Take a little ice cream with a spoon.

That sounds much more natural, and "take off" implies taking a small part, but doesn't have that same connotation of snapping something with your hands, which... wouldn't really apply to ice cream.

Comment: And what "spoon off"? Can it be used to "take off a little ice-cream with a spoon? "Spoon off a little ice-cream".

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish - I'd generally use that more in the case of a tub of ice cream, not a block, but yes, I suppose that would work as well.

Comment: And can "scoop off" be used when talking about taking a little ice-cream off with a spoon after putting it on a plate?

Answer (score 0):

Ice-cream *as a substance* is an uncountable noun. You can count *bowls*, *cones*, or *types/flavours* of ice-cream, but any measurable quantity of the stuff is just "ice-cream" whether it is a 50ml tub or a giant vat.

Therefore it is **wrong** to say:

> "..a small **part** of ice-cream"

This should be either "a small part of *the* ice-cream", or "a small *amount* of ice-cream".

That out of the way, the most idiomatic way to say what you are trying to say is probably as already answered by @Mithrandir:

> *Take* a little ice-cream with a spoon.

With "stick ice-creams" (I presume you mean individual ice-creams on a stick or cones) then the ice-cream is already portioned and so it is a *countable item* for the reason explained above. If you wanted to describe breaking off part of an ice-cream on a stick you would use the definite article and say:

> Break a small part off *the* ice-cream.

Comment: Does "break off" sound okay to you with "popsicle" and not with a brick?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that ice cream is always uncountable; asking something like "Who wants an ice cream?" is perfectly natural. Of course, that tends to be in the sense of an individual ice cream from a van/shop rather than a scoop from a tub.

Comment: @Showsni Read my answer again. It is only uncountable as a substance. I explain that as soon as you divide it into bowls, tubs, scoops, whatever, then you can count those things. If, idiomatically, you refer to "an ice-cream cone" as simply "an ice-cream" that is a case of the same word being used for a different thing.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish "break off" seems idiomatically okay with something solid and countable like a popsicle, but I don't think you would do such a thing with a spoon - more likely with your teeth or some other means.

Comment: And can "scoop off" be used insted of "taken off with a spoon" after a little ice-cream is sliced off with a kinfe and put on a plate and eaten with a spoon? Or will it be used only when the ice-cream is in the tub?